# EPPlus is rounding up a large number

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, epplus

I am using EPPlus to generate an excel report in ASP.Net. I have the following code in use:

`aCell.Value = CDec(aValue)`

`aCell` is of type `OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRange`.

This works fine most of the time. However, when `aValue` is 201600000000515561, the cell in Excel is set with the value of 201600000000516000.

Stepping through the code and watching the value of `aCell.Value` shows that the correct value being set. But when the excel is opened, the value has been rounded up to the next 1000.

Does anybody have a solution or is this a bug in EPPlus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not an `Epplus` thing, more of an Excel thing.  Because of the way excel stores numbers you have up to 15 significant figures after which excel basically inserts 0's.  If you count `201600000000515561` starting from the left you will see this.  Have a look at this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel

I think the most popular work around would be to store the numbers as text which of course leads to its own set of issues.  Here is a good thread on it:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/15-digit-number-limitation-non-text-workaround/a4974853-7c3c-4830-8562-2e88369d981b?auth=1

Comment: Thanks! I think we'll need to store it as text.